# Loyalty in Salesforce, how we can get loyalty details

Tags: trigger

I have questions in my mind about the loyalty programs:

- Need to fetch the loyalty data using Loyalty Number
- Also need to create Account/Contact using Loyalty details.

What is the best to implement this? Using Trigger or Process Builder or workflow?

Comment: AFAIK SF does not have a standard loyalty component. As such if you need to know best practices around implementation of your custom loyalty program you are going to have to provide a lot more detail and be as specific as possible. [Ask] - Also, what does this have to do with Salesforce 2 Salesforce?

Comment: I assume this must be achieved using the Integration. Loyalty system must be some other system..